# Renamed virtual environment but now it can't locate pip

Tags: bash, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I'm working with `virtualenvwrapper` and renamed an environment. I've recently tried to download using pip install but the environment can't locate pip in the python files because the `pathing` is still:

```
/Users/ME/.virtualenvs/OLDENV/bin/python3
```

When it needs to be

```
/Users/ME/.virtualenvs/NEWENV/bin/python3
```

How do I change that path?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out its possible to make a link from the correct path to the incorrect one with the command:

```
ln -s /Users/ME/.virtualenvs/OLDENV/bin/python3 /Users/ME/.virtualenvs/NEWENV/bin/python3
```

formatted

```
ln -s incorrectpath correctpath
```